SAML for Blazor Server Side applications .Net 8
I would like to implement SAML so I have only one authentication service for my various applications. All applications will be Blazor Server .net 8 apps.
Can I implement using ITfoxtec?
If yes, are there and samples & tutorials as I'm very green on the subject.
Thanks
JP

I do not have a Blazor Server sample at this time. But it is more or less the same as ASP.NET Core 8.0 shown in this sample https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/main/test/TestWebAppCore

Hi Anders
Thanks for your reply. I'm checking your samples. In the sample file
test\TestIdPCore\Controllers\AuythController.cs, before validating the user, you're suggesting to launch the login GUI (// ****  Handle user login e.g. in GUI ****). How can you achieve this from within the Action method and then return back inside the same method with the user ID/name?
JP

It is not possible within the action method it self. You need to build a UI sequence. It is probably an IdP you need like FoxIDs (https://www.foxids.com).
